# What is Netherlands?

Tags: pattern

Peru = 4

Japan = 5

Greece = 6

Georgia = 7

Australia = 8

Mauritius = 9

New Zealand = 10

Netherlands = ?

Why?

Comment: Why break the progression?  Should the last question be, "Honduras = ?"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Netherlands is

> 9

because

> Its capital, Amsterdam, has 9 letters.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out the red herring in that rot13(Vg nccrnef gb or gur ahzore bs yrggref va gur pbhagel anzr, ohg Nhfgenyvn oernxf guvf ehyr)

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking something like "number of letters between the first consonant and the end of the word, inclusive." Then I remembered that "U" is a vowel too!